# Junit test not able to access the GAE datastore in local junit test

Tags: java, google-app-engine, testing, junit, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Spring MVC in eclipse and running junit test in local dev server. Junit test not able to access the datastore of GAE. Is there any connection or settings required to access the GAE dev server while test Junit locally . 
// code as follows

private LocalServiceTestHelper helper;

```
    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {

        File dbContents = new File("war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin");
        helper =  new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig()
                          .setBackingStoreLocation(dbContents.getAbsolutePath())
                          .setStoreDelayMs(4000)
                          .setNoStorage(true)
                          ) {

          };
          this.helper.setUp();

            LocalDatastoreService dsService = (LocalDatastoreService)LocalServiceTestHelper.getLocalService(LocalDatastoreService.PACKAGE);
            dsService.setNoStorage(false);
            CustomerPageJDO  CustomerPageJDO = new CustomerPageJDO();
            CustomerPageJDO.setCUID("fac54bca-d593-44c6-8c84-6b4d765eb35f");
            accountJDO.setKey("fac54bca-d593-44c6-8c84-6b4d765eb35f");
            accountJDO.setCompanyKey("fac54bca-d593-44c6-8c84-6b4d765eb35f");
            accountJDO.setCurrentplanType("freePlan_v3");
            planJDO.setPlanId("freePlan_v3");
            planJDO.setPlanName("Free Plan");
            pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
            pm.makePersistent(CustomerPageJDO);
            pm.makePersistent(accountJDO);
            pm.makePersistent(planJDO);

    }


    public void testPersistaccountJDOs1()
    {

     List<AccountJDO> accountJDOList = null;
         PersistenceManager pm;

        //Ensure the accountJDO does not already exist in datasource
        pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        boolean notFound = false;
        try
        {
            accountJDO=pm.getObjectById(AccountJDO.class, "fac54bca-d593-44c6-8c84-6b4d765eb35f");
            planJDO=   pm.getObjectById(PlanJDO.class,accountJDO.getCurrentplanType());
            System.out.println("accountJDO"+gson.toJson(accountJDO));

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            notFound = true;
            System.out.println("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            pm.close();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsert2() {

     testPersistaccountJDOs1();

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown11()
    {
    this.helper.tearDown();
    }
```

Comment: For starters, do you need to use a disk-based datastore for your tests?  If not, it's simpler to use the memory-only approach.  What errors or symptoms are you encountering?

Answer (score 4):

if you need do test datastore (GAE) you should follow the steps ([here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting)) add jars

then  you can test   for example:

```
public class DatastoreTest {

private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
            new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

@Before
public void setUp() {
    helper.setUp();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
     helper.tearDown();
}

@Test
public void queryTest(){
    DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Entity directoty = new Entity("Directory");
    directoty.setProperty("email", "test@localhost");
    directoty.setProperty("name", "edy");
    ds.put(directoty);      
    assertEquals(1,ds.prepare(new Query("Directoty")).countEntities(withLimit(10)));        
}

}
```